# Database Software to store 1TB Data

Tags: mysql, sqlite, database

I am looking for a Database software where I can store 1TB+ Data.
The average size of a row is going to be 5KB.
I have been doing my homework on this for the past month and I have shortlisted two software:

1. SQLite
2. MySQL MyISAM

Essentially, the database should not use too much additional data to store rows and it should be ACID compliant.
I am open to any other DB software suggestion as well.
The application I plan to use is going to have one concurrent connection only.

SQLite is good and meets the requirements except that, when you delete a ROW it will not be delete the data from the file and keep the freed up resources till the data is overwritten by new data. One needs to use VACUUM to clean the free resources which can take quite a lot time and resources. SQLite is also very efficient in storing the data with respect to its size. It doesn't add much data to the contents. SQLite also doesn't allow to separate the INDEX file so that it can be put on a SSD for faster lookups.

MySQL MyISAM is good and it is also VERY efficient in storing the data and doesnt add contents. But MyISAM is not ACID compliant and it can lead to data loss incase of a power failure, etc. INNODB on the otherhand is not efficient to store the data and additional data it adds to store each row is pretty high compared to MyISAM.

So is there any Free Database software which overcomes these constraints or this is the best option I have?

Comment: "innodb.. is not efficient..." - compared to what?

Comment: @ethrbunny seems like he's been reading 10 year old FUD.

Comment: Is the efficiency of disk storage really your biggest concern when selecting a database engine? I haven't seen that as a concern since hard drives cost a dollar per megabyte...

Comment: @ethrbunny innodb is using more space than MyISAM and SQLite.

Comment: @Neville the purpose of this software is to backup data. So its going to be useful to save space. I know Per MB cost is very very low. But the purpose of the software I am designing is to make multiple points of backup and hence space usage is critical.

Answer (score 3):

You should ask yourself how you are going to use that data. 1TB is large, but managable, but the question is how this data is going to be stored. Is it a single table or a relational structure? Is there any structure at all, or are you benefited more by a database like MongoDB that essentially lets you store objects.

The number of reads vs number of writes, those are numbers that are more important.

I think right now you are focusing too much on overhead size. A couple of extra GBs won't cost you, but migrating to a different database because you made the wrong choice will.

Comment: It is a relational structure. MongoDB takes 2-3 times the amount of space to store any data. I agree with the overhead point, but I was just curious if a better software exists. There will be writes more often as well as reads.